# How to unit test a stack ADT without knowing its implementation

Tags: unit-testing, data-structures

Assume that a stack has the following functions, `pop`, `push`, `peek` and `toArray`.

If I would like to write a unit test for, say, the push operation, how can this be done without knowing the underlying implementation? One possibility is to push something to an empty stack and test the `stack.toArray()` against expected result, but that involves a function that is not under test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bring up kind of an interesting question.  In truth, you have to test an ADT based on usage patterns, not individual methods.

Consider the requirements for a stack:

- When I push an item X to a stack, I expect no response.

Well, that's certainly testable, but it's built into the return type, which is `void` or `unit`.

There's nothing directly observable about just the push action.  Rather, it's specific combinations of actions that define a behaviour.

- When I push an item X to an empty stack, I expect X to be on the top of the stack with nothing underneath.

Hmm.  This tests `push`, but as you noted, you can't really resolve the second half without the other stack functions.

In a case like this, does it matter what happens when you push? No! What you care about is that some sequence of operations leads to a verifiable and consistent result.

This is true of unit testing in general: when you can, test each function individually.  But when it doesn't make sense to do so, use patterns of behaviour instead.

Part of the reason you can't assume that pushing to the stack has an immediate result is that you're never given that guarantee.  For example, imagine that your stack implementation uses a fancy buffer: each time you push, it adds the element to the buffer, but doesn't place it on the formal stack yet.  Then, when you call `peek` or `pop`, it takes care of all the buffered items at once, then performs the operation.  To you, the internals are invisible: all you care is that the total behaviour was consistent with that of a stack.

And that is, in essence, what makes it an ADT.  We care about patterns of behaviour, not detailed implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really test the functions in isolation.  If you want to test `push()` you have to  `pop()` in order to test that that the elements pop out in the correct sequence.

You don't need to use `toArray()` unless you want to write tests for it as well.